# ":not" selector doesn't work with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to show/hide a layer when a user clicks on/out a button. I have this simple code that you can check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HYV4g/):

JQUERY:

```
jQuery(function(){

    jQuery('button.profile-button').on('click', function() {
        jQuery('.login-sidebar').show();
        console.log("executed show");
    });
    jQuery(':not(button.profile-button)').on('click', function() {
        jQuery('.login-sidebar').hide();
        console.log("executed hide");
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<button class="profile-button">Profile</button>
<div class="login-sidebar">Login Sidebar</div>
```

CSS:

```
.login-sidebar { display: none; }
```

but when I click the button, the console shows me how the two events are fired. Is it a bug with `:not` selector? or am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Try `button:not(.profile-button)` or some other other selector before the pseudo `:not`

Comment: Your issue is click event bubbling http://jsfiddle.net/HYV4g/3/

Comment: This is expensive. You truly wanna add a "click" event on EVERYTHING but the button? I bet "login-sidebar" is a kind of popup. I would rather add a DIV with 100% width and 100% height of the document and add the click listener on it.If login-sidebar is on top of hit, it's gonna do precisly was you wanna do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do that is by not using `:not`, but filtering inside the event handler

```
jQuery(function($){
   $(document).on('click', function(e) {
     $('.login-sidebar').toggle( $(e.target).closest('.profile-button').length > 0 );
   });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/HYV4g/2/)

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that clicking on the `.login-sidebar` element, it is also hidden, when it actually shouldn't. I've tried for a while, but I'm not able to achieve it...

Comment: @ManoloSalsas - You just have to filter out the sidebar as well -> http://jsfiddle.net/HYV4g/4/

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for your double answer :) It would be fine to add this snippet code too.

Answer (score 0):

try `$("*:not(button.profile-button)")` but it is a pretty expensive select if you have a lot of elements in the DOM.

Comment: This doesn't change anything.

Comment: It isn't any different from the original code in the question. `":not()"` implies `"*:not()"`

Comment: oh I see, that's what he meant.